# IE7, Standards mode vs "IE7 Standards" mode

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, standards, doctype, internet-explorer-10

I have a fairly simple HTML5 website going with some jquery/javascript and CSS.  It looks fine in Chrome, FF and IE8, 9 and 10.  However, when I switch the browser mode to IE7 it doesn't look right.  If I change the document mode to "standards" it looks correct again, still in IE7 mode.  Please see the screenshot for clarification.  Can someone explain the difference between "Standards" mode and "IE7 Standards" mode?  And how can I change the "page default"?

[image: IE10 Debugger]

Comment: Or does "Standards" at the top mean IE10 standards?

Comment: Add

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">`
in your `<head>` tag.

Comment: Nailed it. Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to Add
 `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">`

in your `<head>` tag.

This will force IE to use latest rendering engine even in chrome frame .

Comment: So does that mean it will not work correctly in actual IE7?  I'll be testing later today.

Comment: i cannot say for sure because afterall "it is Internet Explorer!" . I recommend dropping support for IE 7 since it has only 1% usage [IE statistics](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp)